# How to install Windows 10 Core on Raspberry Pi 2 without a real (physical) machine

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, dism

I only have a Windows 8.1 x64 PC and a Raspberry Pi 2. I have some problems that prevent me from installing Windows 10 on my PC.

In this situation, is there any way to install "Windows 10 IoT Core" to the SD card on Raspberry Pi2?

I tried the following:

1. Using a virtual machine - Windows 10 x64 Preview on VM Player, but it failed. I used:

   `dism.exe /Apply-Image /ImageFile:flash.ffu /ApplyDrive:\\.\PhysicalDrive1 /SkipPlatformCheck` -> Error 87? I forgot the number
2. I only copied "dism.exe" file from "window10x64 .iso" file in sources folder.
   and tried the following, but failed:

   `dism.exe /Apply-Image /ImageFile:flash.ffu /ApplyDrive:\\.\PhysicalDrive1 /SkipPlatformCheck` -> Error 87? same
3. I only copied "dism.exe" file from "window10x86 .iso" file in sources folder.
   and tried the following, but failed:

   `dism.exe /Apply-Image /ImageFile:flash.ffu /ApplyDrive:\\.\PhysicalDrive1 /SkipPlatformCheck` -> Error 87? same

So now I know that the "dism.exe" that i called is only for Windows 8, not for Windows 10.

If the ".ffu" installer exists, it is not problem anymore, but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this earlier today with mine and it works. From the iso, without your VM, mount it as a virtual Cd drive (you can use [MagicISO Virtual CD/DVD Manager](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm)) Then open the CD, and run the .msi.

Install python and download [ffu2img.py3](https://github.com/t0x0/random/blob/master/ffu2img.py3) (You may have to copy and paste it into notepad) to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft IoT\FFU\RaspberryPi2.

Now open a cmd window as an administrator and type,

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft IoT\FFU\RaspberryPi2\
C:\Python34\python.exe ffu2img.py flash.ffu
```

Then you have the img file you can write to the sd card just like raspbian. =)

Edit: If you already have the ffu file, skip the first section.